# When not or should use get() in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to understand when/not to use `get();` in Laravel 5.

> PHP warning:  Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

[Google shows me answers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Missing%20argument%201%20for%20Illuminate%5CSupport%5CCollection%3A%3Aget()&oq=Missing%20argument%201%20for%20Illuminate%5CSupport%5CCollection%3A%3Aget()&aqs=chrome..69i57.286j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to their issue but no one really explains when you should/not use it.

**Example:**

```
App\User::first()->timesheets->where('is_completed', true)->get(); // error
App\Timesheet::where('is_completed', true)->get(); // no error
```

**Fix:**

```
App\User::first()->timesheets()->where('is_completed', true)->get(); // no error
```

Noticed the **timesheets()** and not timesheets? Could I have a detail explanation for what is going on, please?

I'm coming from a Ruby background and my code is failing as I do not know when to use `()` or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to describe this as best I can, this `()` notation after a property returns an instance of a builder, let's take an example on relationships,

Say you have a `User` model that has a one-to-many relationship with `Posts`,

If you did it like this:

```
$user = App\User::first();

$user->posts();
```

This here will return a relationship instance because you appended the `()`, now when should you append the `()`? you should do it whenever you want to **chain** other methods on it, for example:

```
$user->posts()->where('some query here')->first();
```

Now I will have a the one item I wanted.

And if I needed say all posts I can do this:

```
$user->posts;
```

or this

```
$user->posts()->latest()->get();
$user->posts()->all()->get();
```

So the key thing here is, whenever you want to chain methods onto an eloquent query use the `()`, if you just want to retrieve records or access properties directly on those records then do it like this:

```
$user->posts->title;
```

Comment: This makes my brain happy `whenever you want to chain other methods`

Answer (score 2):

Well, `->timesheet` returns a collection, where `->timesheet()` returns a builder.
On a Collection you can use `->where()`, and `->get('fieldname')`, but no `->get()`.
The `->get()` method can be used on a builder though, but this will return a collection based on the builder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `->timesheets` you are accessing a variable, which returns the value of it (in this case an instance of Collection).

When you use `->timesheets()` you are invoking whatever is assigned to the variable, which in this case returns an instance of Builder.

whilst pascalvgemert's answer does answer your problem regarding Laravel, it does not explain the difference between accessing or invoking a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' you are facing is due to the feature of being able to [query relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

When accessing a relation like a property, `->timesheets`, the query defined in the relationship is executed and the result (in the form of a `Collection`) is returned to you.

When accessing it like a method, `->timesheets()`, the query builder is returned instead of the resulting collection, allowing you to modify the query if you desire. Since it is then a `Builder` object, you need to call `get()` to get the actual result, which is not needed in the first case.

Answer (score -1):

In simple term

```
$user = App\User::get();
```

is used to fetch multiple data from database

rather

```
$user = App\User::first();
```

is used to fetch single record from database

Comment: Their question was about the difference between `->timesheets()` and `->timesheets`, not `first()` and `get()` - they seem to understand that.